# asp.net mvc BundleConfig - is localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Hi! I want to set bundle optimization to false if I app is started on localhost. Since it is called from app-start method I cant get to the Request object. Other posibility is Transformation config's but they are not used on this project.

Does anybody has some other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you better use the configuration manager. When in 'Debug' mode disable the optimizations, when building in 'Release' mode enable it.

It's also possible to create your own configurations, for instance 'localhost' build.

This is the setting you need to change for the different build configurations:

```
<Optimize>true</Optimize>

or

<Optimize>false</Optimize>
```

This will keep your code cleaner as you don't have to write any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 if (!HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment)
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```